# How to make my h1 in the center of the image background without using absolute position?

Tags: html, css

```css
/*General*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen');

.wrapper {
    max-width: 630px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*Header*/
#header .navbar .navbar-header a {
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}
#header .navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #2C3E50;
    border-color: #2C3E50;
}
#header .navbar {
    border-radius: 0;
}
#header .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color:white;
}
#header .navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
    color: white;
}

/*Content*/
#content .content-content .responsive-image {
    width: 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    z-index:0;
}
#content .content-content h1 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #2c3e50;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
}

/*Footer*/

/*Responsiveness*/

/*Desktop*/
@media screen and (min-width: 992px)
{
    #content .content-content .responsive-image {
        background-image: url('https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/board_black_line_texture_background_wood_55220_1920x1080.jpg');
    }
}

/*Tablet*/
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)
{
    #content .content-content .responsive-image {
        background-image: url('https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/board_black_line_texture_background_wood_55220_1920x1080.jpg');
    }
}

/*Mobile*/
@media screen and (max-width: 767px)
{
    #content .content-content .responsive-image {
        background-image: url('https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/board_black_line_texture_background_wood_55220_1920x1080.jpg');
    }
}

/*Custom*/
@media screen and (max-width: 574px)
{
    #content .content-content .responsive-image {
        background-image: url('https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/board_black_line_texture_background_wood_55220_1920x1080.jpg');height:250px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Magic Gate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Custom.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Magic Gate</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Play</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Log Out</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="content-content">
            <img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/board_black_line_texture_background_wood_55220_1920x1080.jpg" class="responsive-image">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h1>Welcome to Magic Gate</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

I don't want to use absolute positioning because it disrupts the centering of objects/controls at the center of the banner. Can you help me with this one without also changing the img to a div background unless it will be responsive, since everything is responsive. My goal is to center the h1 text at the middle of the banner.

Comment: What is your reason for not wanting to set the image to a background image? It has always been my understanding that an `img` element is for images that are part of the content, and the `background-img` property was meant to be used for exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: just use `display:flex` in css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` in css I am just posting an example to how to get it.

use below css part

```
.content-content {
  position:relative;
}

.wrapper {
    max-width: 630px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/01w7qm6f/)**

Comment: i have an image inside the div, that's why my design is like: the image is on the left side while the textbox is on the right side

Comment: thanks sir!! it helped me i just removed the display flex for some reason.

Comment: `display:flex` keep the `h1` tag in center of the whole image.

Answer (score 1):

Here like you ask, i add `position:relative; top:-250px;` to `h1` . But it is an ugly practice and a realy bad code. `position:absolute;` and `transform:transle()` much more better

```css
/*General*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen');
.wrapper {
    max-width: 630px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


/*Header*/
#header .navbar .navbar-header a{color: white;font-size: 25px;font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;}
#header .navbar-inverse {background-color: #2C3E50;border-color: #2C3E50;}
#header .navbar {border-radius: 0;}
#header .navbar-nav > li > a {color:white;}
#header .navbar {margin-bottom: 0;}
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {color: white;}




/*Content*/

#content .content-content .responsive-image{width: 100%;background-size: 100% 100%;z-index:0;}
#content .content-content h1{font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;color: #2c3e50;font-size: 50px;font-weight: bold;z-index: 2;text-align: center;position:relative;top:-250px;}


/*Footer*/

/*Responsiveness*/

/*Desktop*/
@media screen and (min-width: 992px)
{
#content .content-content .responsive-image{background-image: url('https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/board_black_line_texture_background_wood_55220_1920x1080.jpg');}
}

/*Tablet*/
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)
{
#content .content-content .responsive-image{background-image: url('https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/board_black_line_texture_background_wood_55220_1920x1080.jpg');}
}

/*Mobile*/
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) 
{
#content .content-content .responsive-image{background-image: url('https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/board_black_line_texture_background_wood_55220_1920x1080.jpg');}
}

/*Custom*/
@media screen and (max-width: 574px) 
{
#content .content-content .responsive-image{background-image: url('https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/board_black_line_texture_background_wood_55220_1920x1080.jpg');height:250px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Magic Gate</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Custom.css">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
   <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Magic Gate</a>
       </div>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Play</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
 </div>
 <div id="content">
  <div class="content-content">
   <img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/board_black_line_texture_background_wood_55220_1920x1080.jpg" class="responsive-image">
   <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Welcome to Magic Gate</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="footer">
 </div>
</body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: wow thank you sir, but i want the h1 to center horizontally only, and its position is close to the bottom of the navbar :o

Comment: i forgot to mention, but i will take note your answer it's abig help